# I get error 'Can't use string as a HASH ref while "strict refs"....' when i use my perl code

Tags: perl

im using this perl code to transform JSON into other form with some regular expressions:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use JSON;
use utf8;
my %IDs = ( 'User awx01 logged in.' => 1001 );  
my %levels = ( INFO => 4 );             
my $data = <DATA>;                      
my $json    = data2json($data);         
my $record  = decode_json($json);       
say rec2msg($record);
sub data2json {                         
    my $json = shift;                   
    $json =~ s/[""]/"/g;
    $json =~ s/\\//g;
    $json =~ s/"(\{.*?\})"/$1/;
    return $json;
}
sub rec2msg {                           
    my $r = shift;
    $r->{Message}{message} =~ /(\w+) (\w+) (.+)/;

    my($user,$msg) = ($2,"$1 $3");
    my $ID   = $IDs{$r->{Message}{message}};
    my $level   = $levels{$r->{Message}{level}};

    my $out = "$r->{Message}{'@timestamp'} host CEF:0|OpenSource|AWX|7.0.0|$ID|$msg|$level|src=127.0.0.1 dst=$r->{MessageSourceAddress} duser=$user";
    return $out;
}
__DATA__
{"MessageSourceAddress":"192.168.81.20","EventReceivedTime":"2020-02-06 11:55:14","SourceModuleName":"udp","SourceModuleType":"im_udp","SyslogFacilityValue":1,"SyslogFacility":"USER","SyslogSeverityValue":5,"SyslogSeverity":"NOTICE","SeverityValue":2,"Severity":"INFO","EventTime":"2020-02-06 11:55:14","Hostname":"192.168.81.20","Message":"{\"@timestamp\": \"2020-02-06T08:55:52.907Z\", \"message\": \"User awx01 logged in.\", \"host\": \"awxweb\", \"level\": \"INFO\", \"logger_name\": \"awx.api.generics\", \"stack_info\": null, \"type\": \"other\", \"cluster_host_id\": \"awx-contr-01\", \"tower_uuid\": \"333b4131-495f-4460-8e4b-890241a9d73d\"}"}
```

But im getting this error:

```
2020-03-31 20:48:50 ERROR perl subroutine rec2msg failed with an error: 'Can't use string ("140511667030448") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at /usr/libexec/nxlog/modules/extension/perl/event1.pl line 21.;'
```

What im doing wrong? How could i solve it?

Comment: it says that the error is in line 21: $r->{Message}{message} =~ /(\w+) (\w+) (.+)/;, but i don't understand what is wring there

Comment: The code you posted doesn't yield the error you say it does. First, it doesn't compile (you forgot some quotes when initializing `%IDs`. Second, the only warning it produces is "Use of uninitialized value in concatenation...". Please post a code that does reproduce your error.

Comment: In all likelihood, in your actual code, you either passed a wrong argument to `rec2msg`, or your json decoding didn't work. If it's not the former, the use `Data::Dumper` to inspect `$record`.

Comment: This code, copy-pasted, runs cleanly for me and prints `2020-02-06T08:55:52.907Z host CEF:0|OpenSource|AWX|7.0.0|1001|User logged in.|4|src=127.0.0.1 dst=192.168.81.20 duser=awx01` (this is perl version 5.16).   So ... what kind of a system are you using?  I see a strange path in your error message.

Comment: This looks very similar to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60946239/a-perl-regex-with-conditional-parameters/60946556#60946556). Have you switched usernames?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have JSON embedded in JSON, so you need to decode it twice. This often happens when you have one service passing through the response for another service.

Your `data2json` wasn't decoding that second level, so the value for the `Message` name was still a string. Since that value wasn't a hash reference, you get the error you reported.

You don't want to use a bunch of substitutions on the entire thing because you can inadvertently change things you shouldn't be messing with. Decode the top level just as you did, but then do the same thing for the `Message` value:

```
# read in all the data, even though it looks like a single line. Maybe it won't be later.
my $data = do { local $/; <DATA> };

# decode the first layer
my $decoded = decode_json( $data );

# decode the Message value:
$decoded->{Message} = decode_json( $decoded->{Message} );
```

Now, when you call `rec2msg` it should work out.

Note that this has the opposite problem to reverse it. You can't merely encode the entire thing to JSON again. The value for `Message` still needs to be a string, so you have to encode that first if you want to send it somewhere else. If you are doing that, you probably want to work on a copy. I use `dclone` to make a deep copy so whatever I do to `$encoded` does not show up in `$decoded`:

```
# make a deep copy so nested references aren't shared
use Storable qw(dclone);
my $encoded = dclone( $decoded );
$encoded->{Message} = encode_json( $encoded->{Message} );
my $new_data = encode_json( $encoded );
```

Then `$new_data` will have the same escaping as the original input.

---

Here it is altogether:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use JSON;
use utf8;
my %IDs = ( 'User awx01 logged in.' => 1001 );
my %levels = ( INFO => 4 );

# read in all the data, even though it looks
my $data = do { local $/; <DATA> };
my $decoded = decode_json( $data );
$decoded->{Message} = decode_json( $decoded->{Message} );

say rec2msg($decoded);

sub rec2msg {
    my $r = shift;
    $r->{Message}{message} =~ /(\w+) (\w+) (.+)/;

    my($user,$msg) = ($2,"$1 $3");
    my $ID    = $IDs{$r->{Message}{message}};
    my $level = $levels{$r->{Message}{level}};

    my $out = "$r->{Message}{'@timestamp'} host CEF:0|OpenSource|AWX|7.0.0|$ID|$msg|$level|src=127.0.0.1 dst=$r->{MessageSourceAddress} duser=$user";
    return $out;
}
```